# String list in SqlCommand through Parameters in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Working with a SqlCommand in C# I've created a query that contains a IN (list...) part in the where clause. Instead of looping through my string list generating the list I need for the query (dangerous if you think in sqlInjection). I thought that I could create a parameter like:

```
SELECT blahblahblah WHERE blahblahblah IN @LISTOFWORDS
```

Then in the code I try to add a parameter like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("word", typeof(string));
foreach (String word in listOfWords)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(word);
}
comm.Parameters.Add("LISTOFWORDS", System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured).Value = dt;
```

But this doesn't work.

Questions:

- Am I trying something impossible?
- Did I took the wrong approach?
- Do I have mistakes in this approach?

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do is possible but not using your current approach.  This is a very common problem with all possible solutions prior to SQL Server 2008 having trade offs related to performance, security and memory usage.

[This link shows some approaches for SQL Server 2000/2005](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters)

[SQL Server 2008 supports passing a table value parameter.](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You want to think about where that list comes from.  Generally that information is in the database somewhere.  For example, instead of this:

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE ID IN (1,2,3)
```

You could use a subquery like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE ID IN ( SELECT TableID FROM [OtherTable] WHERE OtherTableID= @OtherTableID )
```

Comment: Unfortunately the information is not on another table. Is the result of some data gathering.

But is a good approach that I'll write down for future uses. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, you're trying to pass a list as a SQL parameter.

Some folks have attempted this before with limited success:

[Passing Arrays to Stored Procedures](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/passing_arrays_to_stored_procedures.htm)

[Arrays and Lists in SQL 2005](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html)

[Passing Array of Values to SQL Server without String Manipulation](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2007/03/18/passing-an-array-of-values-to-sql-server-stored-procedure-without-parsing-string-manipulation.aspx)

[Using MS SQL 2005's XML capabilities to pass a list of values to a command](http://codebetter.com/blogs/karlseguin/archive/2006/05/08/144263.aspx)

Comment: The first link talks about a table variable. This is what I've created with the DataTAble. But in this case I cannot make mssql to swallow it.


I guess the idea is gonna be create a table guid,word. Insert there and then delte by guid.

Answer (score 1):

- Am I trying something impossible?

No, it isn't impossible.

- Did I took the wrong approach?

Your approach is not working (at least in .net 2)

- Do I have mistakes in this approach?

I would try "Joel Coehoorn" solution (2nd answers) if it is possible.
Otherwise, another option is to send a "string" parameter with all values delimited by an separator. Write a dynamic query (build it based on values from string) and execute it using "exec".

Another solution will be o build the query directly from code. Somthing like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0; i< listOfWords.Count; i++)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("p{0},",i);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("p"+i.ToString(), listOfWords[i]);
}

comm.CommandText = string.Format(""SELECT blahblahblah WHERE blahblahblah IN ({0})", 
sb.ToString().TrimEnd(','));
```

The command should look like:

```
SELECT blah WHERE blah IN (p0,p1,p2,p3...)...p0='aaa',p1='bbb'
```

In MsSql2005, "IN" is working only with 256 values.

Comment: On the bottom query I get an error on the first occurrence of p0.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting the parameter as a comma delimited string of values and use a Split function in SQL to turn that into a single column table of values and then you can use the IN feature.

http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=50648 - Split Functions

Comment: That's quite Sql Injection prone :(

Comment: That's a patently dangerous approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the list as a string in a parameter, you could just build the query dynamically.

DECLARE @query varchar(500)
SET @query = 'SELECT blah blah WHERE blahblah in (' + @list + ')'
EXECUTE(@query)

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem, I think there is now way to do this directly over the ADO.NET API.

You might consider inserting the words into a temptable (plus a queryid or something) and then refering to that temptable from the query. Or dynamically creating the query string and avoid sql injection by other measures (e.g. regex checks).

Comment: I'll go with the first option + a bulk sql insert. Perhaps this can save me some SQL I/O

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I've come up with an elegant solution for this that I love to reuse and I think everyone else will find it useful.

First of all you need to create a `FUNCTION` in SqlServer that takes a delimited input and returns a table with the items split into records.

Here is the following code for this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @RowData nvarchar(max),
    @SplitOn nvarchar(5) = ','
)  
RETURNS @RtnValue table 
(
    Id int identity(1,1),
    Data nvarchar(100)
) 
AS  
BEGIN 
    Declare @Cnt int
    Set @Cnt = 1

    While (Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)>0)
    Begin
        Insert Into @RtnValue (data)
        Select 
            Data = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@RowData,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)-1)))

        Set @RowData = Substring(@RowData,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)+1,len(@RowData))
        Set @Cnt = @Cnt + 1
    End

    Insert Into @RtnValue (data)
    Select Data = ltrim(rtrim(@RowData))

    Return
END
```

You can now do something like this:

```
Select Id, Data from dbo.Split('123,234,345,456',',')
```

And fear not, this can't be susceptible to Sql injection attacks.

Next write a stored procedure that takes your comma delimited data and then you can write a sql statement that uses this Split function:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[findDuplicates]
    @ids nvarchar(max)
as
begin
    select ID
      from SomeTable with (nolock)
     where ID in (select Data from dbo.Split(@ids,','))
end
```

Now you can write a C# wrapper around it:

```
public void SomeFunction(List<int> ids)
{
    var idsAsDelimitedString = string.Join(",", ids.Select(id => id.ToString()).ToArray());

    // ... or however you make your connection
    var con = GetConnection();

    try
    {
        con.Open();

        var cmd = new SqlCommand("findDuplicates", con);

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ids", idsAsDelimitedString));

        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        // .... do something here.

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // catch an exception?
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```