# 'insert into' with array

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm wondering if there's a way to use 'insert into' on a list of values.  I'm trying to do this:

```
insert into tblMyTable (Col1, Col2, Col3)
     values('value1', value2, 'value3')
```

So, what I'm trying to say is that value2 will be an array of strings.  I'm going to put this in C# but the SQL statement is all I need really.  I know I could just use a foreach and loop through my array but I figured there might be a better way sort of like the SELECT statement here: [SQL SELECT * FROM XXX WHERE columnName in Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393886/sql-select-from-xxx-where-columnname-in-array).  It seems like a single query would be much more efficient than one at a time.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.  Thanks fellas!

Comment: You can specify multiple 'values' lines. I would just generated the SQL programatically in this case (you can even use placeholders with the SqlCommand stuff! no ugly-string injection required) . If you really want to pass an "array", consider the XML type and a sproc to do -- well, pretty much just what the C# code would do. You can decompose the XML type into a table-type, but at the expense of a sproc/T-SQL, not sure if that's an approach you *really* want to take.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know you could do multiple 'values' lines until now.  Placeholders in SqlCommand()?  Can you give me a small example of what you're talking about?  The only placeholders I've heard of is for ASP.NET but my app is a Windows Form...

Comment: @pst - You answered my question but I can't give you credit since it's in the comments.  Repost in answers if you care...

Comment: After thinking about it more, it'd just be a PITA to generate all the values with placeholders (I do this a good bit for *different* complex problems). Just running all the inserts in the *same transaction* should have approximately the same effect, pathological cases with triggers and such aside, but be much simpler -- just using the same [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) (part of ADO.NET, can be considered the "most basic" access) over N times in a loop would be much simpler. Using XML, etc, are already covered below :)

Comment: Alright, I'll just loop through or figure out a way to use multiple 'values'.  Either way, all the stuff below looks like more than I can handle right now.  The XML looks pretty nice, so I'll give the answer down there to cyberwiki...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this type of insert statement

```
insert into tblMyTable (Col1, Col2, Col3)
select 'value1', value, 'value3'
from dbo.values2table('abc,def,ghi,jkl',',',-1) V
```

The **'value'**, **'value3'** and '**abc,def,ghi,jkl'** are the 3 varchar parameters you need to set in C# SQLCommand.

This is the supporting function required.

```
CREATE function dbo.values2table
(
@values varchar(max),
@separator varchar(3),
@limit int -- set to -1 for no limit
) returns @res table (id int identity, [value] varchar(max))
as
begin
declare @value varchar(50)
declare @commapos int, @lastpos int
set @commapos = 0
select @lastpos = @commapos, @commapos = charindex(@separator, @values, @lastpos+1)
while @commapos > @lastpos and @limit <> 0
begin
    select @value = substring(@values, @lastpos+1, @commapos-@lastpos-1)
    if @value <> '' begin
        insert into @res select ltrim(rtrim(@value))
        set @limit = @limit-1
    end
    select @lastpos = @commapos, @commapos = charindex(@separator, @values, @lastpos+1)
end
select @value = substring(@values, @lastpos+1, len(@values))
if @value <> '' insert into @res select ltrim(rtrim(@value))
return
end
GO
```

The parameters used are:

1. ',' = delimiter
2. -1  = all values in the array, or N for just first N items

## solution is above, alternatives below

Or, if you fancy, a purely CTE approach not backed by any split function (watch comments with <<<)

```
;WITH T(value,delim) AS (
     select 'abc,def,ghi', ','   --- <<< plug in the value array and delimiter here
),  CTE(ItemData, Seq, I, J) AS (
    SELECT
        convert(varchar(max),null),
        0,
        CharIndex(delim, value)+1,
        1--case left(value,1) when ' ' then 2 else 1 end
    FROM T
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        convert(varchar(max), subString(value, J, I-J-1)),
        Seq+1,
        CharIndex(delim, value, I)+1, I
    FROM CTE, T
    WHERE I > 1 AND J > 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        SubString(value, J, 2000),
        Seq+1,
        CharIndex(delim, value, I)+1, 0
    FROM CTE, T
    WHERE I = 1 AND J > 1
)

--- <<< the final insert statement
insert into tblMyTable (Col1, Col2, Col3)
SELECT 'value1', ItemData, 'value3'
FROM CTE
WHERE Seq>0
```

XML approach

```
-- take an XML param
declare @xml xml
set @xml = '<root><item>abc</item><item>def</item><item>ghi</item></root>'

insert into tblMyTable (Col1, Col2, Col3)
SELECT 'value1', n.c.value('.','varchar(max)'), 'value3'
FROM @xml.nodes('/root/item') n(c)

-- heck, start with xml string
declare @xmlstr nvarchar(max)
set @xmlstr = '<root><item>abc</item><item>def</item><item>ghi</item></root>'

insert tblMyTable (Col1, Col2, Col3)
SELECT 'value1', n.c.value('.','varchar(max)'), 'value3'
FROM (select convert(xml,@xmlstr) x) y
cross apply y.x.nodes('/root/item') n(c)
```

In C# code, you would only use 4 lines starting with "insert tblMyTable ..." and parameterize the @xmlstr variable.

Comment: Why?  If this doesn't have to happen too often, it's a perfectly cromulent way to do this.

Comment: @pst - I'm in the dark; what's this about??

Comment: Heh. +1 for being [cromulent](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Cromulent).

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to cry too.  These solutions are all over my head.  I was thinking it would be a much simpler query that I would be able to easily put in SqlCommand().  I was wrong!

Comment: @snickered - okay, I went over my head. reformatted first part to be clearer

Comment: @cyberkiwi - Thanks, I'll give those 4 lines a shot... I'll probably be back later to post another question about it.  We'll see.

Comment: +1 for the effort! It is not what I am looking for but your function gave me an idea on how I would solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using SQL 2008 and C# your best bet is probably to use a a [table valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx)  and then join to it.

This is better than passing a comma delimited string because you don't have to worry about quotes and commas in your values.

**update** 
Another option is to use the [xml data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189887%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx).

Pre-SQL 2005 another option is to pass an XML string and using [OPENXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918.aspx). If you use an XMLWriter to create your string it will take care of making sure your xml is valid

Comment: OPENXML.. really? Not the XML data type and XPath queries?

Comment: @cyperkiwi don't know what I was thinking. Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
-- This table is meant to represent the real table you
-- are using, so when you write this replace this one.
DECLARE @tblMyTable TABLE
(
 Value1 VARCHAR(200)
 , Value2 VARCHAR(200)
 , Value3 VARCHAR(200)
);

-- You didn't say how you were going to get the string
-- array, so I can't do anything cool with that. I'm
-- just going to say we've made a table variable to
-- put those values in. A user-defined table type
-- might be in order here.
DECLARE @StringArray TABLE
(
 Value VARCHAR(200)
);

INSERT INTO @StringArray
VALUES ('Jeremy'), ('snickered'), ('LittleBobbyTables'), ('xkcd Reference');

DECLARE @Value1 VARCHAR(200) = 'This guy --->';
DECLARE @Value3 VARCHAR(200) = ' <--- Rocks!';

-- I want to cross apply the two constant values, so
-- they go into a CTE, which makes them as good as
-- in a table.
WITH VariablesIntoTable AS
(
 SELECT
  @Value1 AS Value1
  , @Value3 AS Value3
)
-- Cross applying the array couples every row in the
-- array (which is in a table variable) with the two
-- variable values.
, WithStringArray AS
(
 SELECT
  VariablesIntoTable.Value1
  , StringArray.Value AS Value2
  , VariablesIntoTable.Value3
 FROM VariablesIntoTable
 CROSS APPLY @StringArray StringArray
)
INSERT INTO @tblMyTable
-- The output clause allows you to see what you just
-- inserted without a separate select.
OUTPUT inserted.Value1, inserted.Value2, inserted.Value3
SELECT
 WithStringArray.Value1
 , WithStringArray.Value2
 , WithStringArray.Value3
FROM WithStringArray
```