# Pass table valued parameter using ADO.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net

How to pass table valued parameter to stored procedure using ADO.NET?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/5595353/8479

Answer (score 81, accepted):

1. **Create type in SQL Server**:

   ```
   CREATE TYPE [dbo].[MyDataType] As Table
   (
       ID INT,
       Name NVARCHAR(50)
   )
   ```
2. **Create Procedure**:

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedure]
   (
       @myData As [dbo].[MyDataType] Readonly
   )
   AS

   BEGIN
       SELECT * FROM @myData
   END
   ```
3. **Create DataTable in C#**:

   ```
   DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable("MyDataType");
   myDataTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
   myDataTable.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(Int32));
   myDataTable.Rows.Add("XYZ", 1);
   myDataTable.Rows.Add("ABC", 2);
   ```
4. **Create SQL Parameter**:

   ```
   SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();
   parameter.ParameterName = "@myData";
   parameter.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured;
   parameter.Value = myDataTable;
   command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
   ```

Comment: This is applicable only in Sql Server 2008

Comment: I meant this is available only Sql server 2008 and above and so It would work in 2012 too.

Comment: **Note**, I believe that the columns from the DataTable you create in Step 3 must match column order you define in your Table Type in Step 1.  You are just passing in a grid of data and then SQL Server reads it in positionally.  In fact, the actual column name you give it in .NET is just a string for your own benefit - it can be different as SQL won't use it.

Comment: Can a `DataTable` created in C# be used in a Entity Framework LINQ query?

Comment: @KyleMit You are correct - the column order must match. xlink to related SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628276/fastmember-column-order-preservation

Comment: What do you do if you want to use a TVP in a single SQL query and not inside a stored-procedure? Do you need the `TYPE` declaration at all in that case?

Comment: As per @MatthewM's answer you need to set `parameter.TypeName` for this to work https://stackoverflow.com/a/22948571/8479

Answer (score 20):

I tried this and received the exception:

> The table type parameter '@MyDataType' must have a valid type name.

I had to set the "TypeName" property of the SqlParameter:

```
parameter.TypeName = "MyDataType";
```

Comment: Adding the db schema as part of the table name did it for me : DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable("dbo.MyDataType");

Answer (score 0):

This question is a duplicate of [How to pass table value parameters to stored procedure from .net code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5595353/1414000).  Please see that question for an example illustrating the use of either a `DataTable` or an `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>`.

Answer (score 0):

For multilinguals, a little late to the show:

a) elsewhere on tsql

```sql
--- create a vector data type
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[ItemList] AS TABLE([Item] [varchar](255) NULL)
```

b)

```vb
Dim Invoices As New DataTable("dbo.ItemList") 'table name is irrelevant
Invoices.Columns.Add("Invoice", GetType(String))
...
        With .SqlCommand.Parameters
            .Clear()
            .Add(New Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter() With {
                        .SqlDbType = Data.SqlDbType.Structured,
                        .Direction = Data.ParameterDirection.Input,
                        .ParameterName = "@Invoices",
                        .TypeName = "dbo.ItemList",
                        .Value = Invoices})
        End With
...
   ' using  store procedure
   .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM dbo.rpt(@invoices) "
   ' or direct reference is a select
   .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM dbo.invoicedata" +
        "where ((select count(*) from @invoices) = 0 or "+
             "InvoiceNumber in (select distinct * from @Invoices))
```

Answer (score -6):

You can prefix with Exec

```
using( SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection( "Server=.;database=employee;user=sa;password=12345" ) )
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand( " exec ('drop table '+@tab)" , con );
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@tab" ,"Employee" );
        con.Open( );
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery( );
    }
```