# How to write insert query for textbox and datagridview values for two different tables?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview, textbox

I am using text boxes and data grid view in my winform application. Where text boxes values and data grid view values entered by user should be saved in two different SQL tables,means all textbox entries save in one table and all datagridview entries in another table.

How do I do that?

Here is my stored procedure and tables `Purchase` and `Purchasedetail` respectively.

```
CREATE PROC sp_insert_pdtl (
    @purchase_id varchar(15),
    @purchase_date date,
    @ref_no int,
    @product_id int,
    @product_name nvarchar(50),
    @qty int,
    @price float,
    @tax int,
    @discount int,
    @total int
) AS 

begin transaction

INSERT INTO Purchase(purchase_id, purchase_date, ref_no)
VALUES(@purchase_id, @purchase_date, @ref_no)
INSERT INTO Purchasedetail(product_id, product_name, qty, price, tax, discount, total)
VALUES (@product_id, @product_name, @qty, @price, @tax, @discount, @total)
commit`enter code here`
```

and here is my C# code. However, when I execute this, it doesn't save the data in the two tables.

```
private void SAVE(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlTransaction transaction = con.BeginTransaction())
        {
            auto();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_insert_pdtl", con,transaction);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@purchase_id", textid.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@purchase_date", dateTimePicker1.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ref_no", textrno.Text);
            for (int i = 0; i < datagrid.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_id", datagrid.Rows[i].Cells["product_id"].FormattedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_name", datagrid.Rows[i].Cells["product_name"].FormattedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", datagrid.Rows[i].Cells["qty"].FormattedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", datagrid.Rows[i].Cells["price"].FormattedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tax", datagrid.Rows[i].Cells["tax"].FormattedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@discount", datagrid.Rows[i].Cells["discount"].FormattedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total", datagrid.Rows[i].Cells["total"].FormattedValue);
            }
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            transaction.Commit();
        }                        
        MessageBox.Show("Added Sucessfully", "OUTPUT", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);                           
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

Comment: Why would you expect your code to save data into 2 databases if you're opening only 1 connection? And if you want to duplicate data, what's the problem with reusing your `cmd` object?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to insert one main record and multiple child record, which can’t be done the way you have implemented. It is going to pick only the last child record returned by the `for` loop, all other child records will be ignored.

I think either you should pass all the child records as `XML` or `ADO.NET` table values parameter to the SP and parse these in the SP and insert after the master record.

For the table value  `ADO.NET` parameter check following link.

[Pass table valued parameter using ADO.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409576/pass-table-valued-parameter-using-ado-net)

One more suggestion, if you are using truncation in the code then you don’t require that in the SP level.