# How to create dynamic parameters in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a form that generate inputs dynamically, then I get their values and generate command parameters dynamically.

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);

    SqlCommand cmd =new SqlCommand("insert_op",con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    for (int i = 0; i < Request.Form.Count; i++)
    {
        if (Request.Form["frm_option" + (i + 1)] != null)
        {

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@op" + i, Request.Form["frm_option" + (i + 1)]);
        }
    }
    try
    {
        using (con)
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
```

How can I pass these dynamic parameters to SQL Server stored procedure and how should stored procedure be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to "insert each parameter into separate row" then perhaps it is better to use table variable as a stored prosedure parameter?

Your User Defined Table Type and stored procedure might look like:

```
create type dbo.ValueTableType as table (Value varchar(255))
GO

create procedure dbo.InsertValues
    @Values dbo.ValueTableType readonly
as
begin

    insert into dbo.YourTable (Value)
    select Value from @Values;
end
```

See this ADO.NET example of how to initialize and pass a table parameter to stored procedure https://stackoverflow.com/a/10409710/623190

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this isn't the right design.

To achieve your goal you need to pass multiple values in SQL statment as follows

**SQL**

```
INSERT INTO tbl_options(op_name) VALUES (value1),(value2),...(nthValue)
```

**Code**

Your code will be something like this

```
string command = "INSERT INTO tbl_options(op_name) VALUES";    
for (int i = 0; i < Request.Form.Count; i++)
                {                      
                    if (Request.Form["frm_option" + (i + 1)] != null)
                    {
                        command += "(@op" + i + "),";

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@op" + i, Request.Form["frm_option" + (i + 1)]);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: how should stored procedure be?

Comment: I would recommend to pass a single parameter to the SP and it should be csv list . (I am assuming that all the values are going to single column of the table).

Comment: But I want to insert each parameter into  separate row.

Comment: Yes, you will pass the csv list to stored procedure, then iterate that list to insert it into the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide defaults for every field in the table, so any parameters you do not pass in will get the default. Here I demonstrate defaults of NULL.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sproc_tbl_options_Insert] 
    @op_name nvarchar(50) = NULL,
    @op_somethingelse nvarchar(5) = NULL,
    @op_number int = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [tbl_options] (op_name, op_somethingelse, op_number)
    VALUES (@op_name, @op_somethingelse, @op_number);
END
```