# Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have created a user data table type as below:

```sql
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[UDTPASpecMYTest] AS TABLE(
    [EmpName] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Empaddress] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [EmpCarname] [varchar](max) NULL     
)
GO
```

and declare a procedure as below:

```sql
CREATE procedure [dbo].[test]
(
      @tblPASpecs UDTPASpecMYTest  READONLY    
)
AS
BEGIN
select 1
END
```

While I am calling the procedure from application by passing a datatable it is showing an error:

> "Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with UDTPASpecMYTest".

Code in application:

```cs
DataColumn workCol = dtbl.Columns.Add("EmpName", typeof(String));   
dtbl.Columns.Add("Empaddress", typeof(String));
dtbl.Columns.Add("EmpCarname", typeof(String));
dtbl.Rows.Add("Test", "Test", "Test");
strQuery = "EXEC dbo.test @tblPASpecs=" + dtbl + "";

//call the procedure
CMASConnectionProvider.DMLService.ExecSqlReturnDataSet(strQuery);
```

Comment: You have to pass it as a parameter, you cannot use string concatenation here.

Comment: ...and parameter data type should be `SqlDbType.Structured`

Comment: This should help you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx

Comment: To use SQL user types in C# you must inform its type.
If you're using ADO.Net and are executing a stored procedure, when you define the parameter, you must specify type as SqlDbType.Structured and the type name with name of your Type,  = "dbo.UDTPASpecMYTest";

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409576/pass-table-valued-parameter-using-ado-net) shows how to do it with ADO.Net.

Answer (score 2):

You are only passing the type name (as string) to your stored procedure.
Instead you must pass the table instance, by using SqlParameter object.

Something like this:

```
var connection = CMASConnectionProvider.Connection;
var command = new SqlCommand("dbo.test", connection);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

// Next 2 lines are the point:
var parameter = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tblPASpecs", dtbl); 
parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured; 

// Execute the command according your needs and existing helper classes
// var result = command.Execute();
```

This article explains exactly what you would like to do, please [read here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2112/table-value-parameters-in-sql-server-2008-and-net-c/)

Comment: You really should include the relevant parts of the link in your answer to guard against the the possibility of the link going dead.