# Is it possible to pass a DataTable to an ad-hoc sql query in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, parameterized-query

I'd like to be able to build a parameterized ad-hoc SQL query using Entity Framework which consumes a table-valued parameter.

*NB: The use-case which brought this to my interest was querying for multiple entities given a list of IDs. I want the query planner to be able to cache the plan if possible, but I don't necessarily want to create a stored procedure.*

Suppose I have some ids:

```
IEnumerable<int> ids = new [] {0, 42, -1};
```

If I write an EF query like

```
context.MyEntities
    .Where(e => ids.Contains(e.Id))
```

the generated sql is *not* parameterized, and looks like this:

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
    FROM [MyEntities] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Id] IN (0, 42, -1)
```

What I want to get instead is something like

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
    FROM [MyEntities] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT
        1
        FROM @ids AS [Extent2]
        WHERE [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent1].[Id]
    )
```

which is fully-parameterized.

**Can this be done in an EF ad-hoc query?**

I am aware that it *is* possible to pass table-valued parameters to direct queries using EF (e.g. to a stored procedure), using a `SqlParameter` with `SqlDbType.Structured` and a `DataTable` as its value (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10409710/5181199). When I try the same trick to create an `IQueryable` version of my `ids`, I'm surprised to find the generated SQL actually enumerates the values so it looks like the first (unwanted) SQL example I gave! It also complains `The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection` when I try to execute the query.

---

One hacky way which just about works is to transform the `IEnumerable` IDs into an `IQueryable` in the following way:

- Join the values into a single delimited string `joined`
- Make some kind of string-splitting-and-parsing function with a table-valued output on the DB side (`MyStringSplit`)
- Create an EF 'complex type' for the output structure of the above function, like `public class IntId { public int Id { get; set; } }`
- Use `((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<IntId>("MyStringSplit(@joined)", new ObjectParameter("joined", joined))` to create an `IQueryable` of my IDs.

This produces something like

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
    FROM [MyEntities] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Id] IN (SELECT
        1
        FROM [MyStringSplit](@joined) AS [Extent2]
        WHERE [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent1].[Id]
    )
```

which is close to what I'm after, but is messy and surely doesn't provide the performance benefits of actual table-valued parameters.

**EDIT**: To clarify, what I have in mind is some kind of nice c#-side abstraction which I can use to 'transform' my `IEnumerable` collections into `IQueryable` representations (for a particular context) which get interpreted as table-valued parameters when consumed by EF. We can assume that the necessary table types are already defined SQL-side (e.g. a table type for integer IDs, a table type for string IDs...)

Comment: Unless your definition of "ad-hoc" includes "ad-hoc issuing of `CREATE TYPE` statements with the right structure and maybe dropping them later in a sort of garbage-collected way", then no. Does this assume the requisite TVP type has already been created and the only ad-hoc part is the query itself? T-SQL *itself* has no ad-hoc way to pass table-structured data (if you don't count encoding things in XML or JSON), so it's not really surprising EF doesn't expose something like that.

Comment: It is not possible and if you use IQueryable to try to get that query you will lose performance.

Comment: With regards to the "performance benefits" of TVPs -- it's tempting to assume TVPs must be the fastest, bestest way to pass data because they closely align to the structure, but it's more accurate to say they're nice for allowing you to pass tables at all. There are gotchas with [data layout](http://www.dbdelta.com/sql-server-tvp-performance-gotchas/) and [cardinality assumptions common to table variables](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/04/table-variables-good-temp-tables-sql-2014/) that can trip you up. They're better than parsing strings, for sure, but not the be-all and end-all.

Comment: @JeroenMostert so assuming TVP already exists - is there a way to use it in pure EF queries?

Comment: @JeroenMostert yes, we can assume this part of the definition is not 'ad-hoc'; I have already defined the necessary table types database-side.

Comment: Your links look very helpful for understanding better; I'll take a look...

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar issue where the query store was getting filled up with these kinds of dynamic queries (based on the variable "IN" clause). So we changed it from an EF query to an inline SQL to make it a parameterized query and therefore use a single query plan.

```
IEnumerable<int> ids = new [] {0, 42, -1};
var strIds = string.Join(",", ids);

var names = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>(@"SELECT [NAME]
 FROM [MyEntities] as e
 join STRING_SPLIT(@ids, ',') as i on e.Id = o.value",
  new SqlParameter("@ids", strIds));
```

NOTE: that STRING_SPLIT is available on compatibility level 130 or higher, per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15