# Sql Server Delete Where In

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I already read many posts about this topic.

I'm trying to perform on a real table the following:

```
DELETE FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID in (...)
```

where *in* clause can contain 1,2 or many (>3000) values (deriving from a list in c#)

I haven't problems about triggers, FK...

I can't find a complete sample using temporary table table value, or type.
And I can't understand how can I insert (3000 records) in the temp table/table value/type without having performance problems. I already understand to do the join after.

I would avoid Stored Procedure if possible

Comment: I don't understand the question.  If you are deleting from the table, what is the performance issue with inserts?  Are you using a temporary table, permanent table, or table variable?

Comment: @MitchWheat thanks for comment. Maybe some link? I already read many post on Stackoverflow

Comment: @GordonLinoff my table is real. I can't find a complete sample using the temp table or table value.

Comment: Are you trying to ask how to insert the values in a temporary table and select from it for the `IN`?

Comment: How does c# produce this list?

Comment: I edited my post. @stickybit Yes also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass table valued parameter using ADO.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409576/pass-table-valued-parameter-using-ado-net). Possible duplicate of [How to pass table value parameters to stored procedure from .net code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5595353/1260204)

Comment: @Emanuele, see [Table Valued Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters).

Comment: @DanBracuk I don't use any ORM. `String.Join(",", myList.Select(x => "'" + x + "'"))`

Comment: @Igor It's necessary to use stored procedure? I would avoid it.

Comment: @Emanuele - no, not at all. See the 1st suggested duplicate. It is exactly what you are wanting to do.

Comment: @Emanuele - just ignore the stored procedure specific code, use your query and do a join with the passed in table type value.

Comment: The first link of possible duplicate is clearly wrong. I'm reading the second one. @DanGuzman I already read the documentation but I can't understand some things, so I wrote here...

Comment: @Emanuele, not sure what exactly you don't understand. See http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html for additional C# examples.

Comment: @DanGuzman in your linked article where can i find the answer to my question without stored procedure as i asked? It's very interesting. I will read it. Thanks

Comment: @Emanuele, the only difference without a proc is you set the CommandText properly to your `DELETE` statement, set CommandType.Text, and specify thee type name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [Pass table valued parameter using ADO.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10409710/1260204), that is where this answer was derived from.

1. **Create type in SQL Server**:

   ```
   CREATE TYPE [dbo].[MyDataType] As Table
   (
       cust_id INT
   )
   ```
2. **Create DataTable in C#**:

   ```
   DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable("dbo.MyDataType");
   myDataTable.Columns.Add("cust_id", typeof(Int32));
   myDataTable.Rows.Add(1);
   myDataTable.Rows.Add(2);
   ```
3. **Create SQL Parameter and execute query**:

   ```
   using(var command = new SqlCommand(connection, "DELETE FROM MYTABLE WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @myData WHERE cust_id = ID)"))
   {       
     SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();
     parameter.ParameterName = "@myData";
     parameter.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured;
     parameter.Value = myDataTable;
     command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

     // execute delete
     command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
   ```

Comment: What is the difference with my answer? However, I got two down votes.

Comment: I received 3 closed without trying to understand the question :D
@Emdad you are right but this answer is clearer according to me. And i continue to say that is not a duplicate

Comment: @Emdad - you are missing implementations for step 2 and 3.

Comment: Ok, starting from this answer. If I have 3000 numeric Id, I have to write 3000 myDataTable.Rows.Add. Is it possible to avoid it? Or it's better do a batch insert?

Comment: @Emanuele - no, if you have values you must pass them. Unless you are asking how to write a for/foreach loop? The end result must be values you want to filter on must be added to the table.

Comment: Ok, i will try this solution. I have never used Type before. Thanks

Comment: @Igor, He add only sql server tag. If he will face problem to add C# code, I will add in my answer. But for this case, how  I got down vote?

Comment: @Emdad - I do not know, you are not required to leave a comment when downvoting. The only thing you can do is ask in the comments under your answer and ask the downvoters to explain why the downvoted... maybe they will answer.

Comment: @Igor can you explain me what's the difference between type and table (create, insert, drop)? I think using table i can "stay" in my own database. And with thousands records?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create table variable

```
CREATE TYPE SampleTable AS TABLE
(
        Id INT  
)
GO
```

Step 2: Insert your table variable from your C# List

Step 3: Delete your table data

```
DECLARE @Sample_Id_List SampleTable READONLY
DELETE FROM YourTable WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM @Sample_Id_List)
```

Comment: Ok. Finally a starting point. 2 questions. Have i to drop table SampleTableVariable then? How can I perform insert? I have to write 3000 insert clauses? Better a batch?

Comment: You're creating a type, not a variable. You can't insert into a type, neither select from it.

Comment: @stickybit, Need to create type one time , then insert data from C# code and finally select id from type for delete.

Comment: @Emanuele, you do not need to drop type data. You will insert data from list.

Comment: You can declare a table variable with something like `DECLARE @t TABLE (i int);`, you don't need to create the type before. Of course you can create a type and use it, but then you'd still have to declare a variable with that type. You simply don't do that in your answer.

Comment: Now you are all undestanding that there isn't already a precise answer. I'm reading the Igor's second linked article

Comment: @stickybit, In this case, he need to create type. Because, he will insert data from C# list.So he need to create type one time.

Comment: Insert (step 2) is a normal insert as in a table?

Comment: That's got nothing to do with C#, it works well without a type there too. But either way a variable needs to be declared. One can insert into or select from a type. E.g. try `sqlCommand.CommandText = @"DECLARE @t TABLE (i int); INSERT INTO @t VALUES (7), (9); SELECT * FROM @t;";`.

Comment: @stickybit, I have updated my answer. Thanks for your clarification.

Comment: @stickybit you are right but then I will have n insert to write and it's the same to write one delete with n in values.... (any sql limit but same problem according to me)

Comment: @Emanuele: If you gut _n_ values and there is no way, to select them in the database (e.g. they are in a table and share a common attribute value), you have to transfer them at one point. You can put them in a variable or (temporary) table, to reuse them in subsequent commands without retransfering them but there is no way to circumvent the one transfer.

Comment: @stickybit I have never used the type solution. Is it better to use type or temporary table? Thanks

Comment: @Emanuele, according to your requirement, you need to use type. Because, you have to create type once but for temporary table, you need to create every time to execute delete query. Thanks.