# C# Efficiently delete 50000 records in batches using SQLBulkCopy or equivalent library

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bulk, bulk-delete

I'm using this library to perform bulk delete in batches like following:

```
  while (castedEndedItems.Any())
  {
    var subList = castedEndedItems.Take(4000).ToList();
    DBRetry.Do(() => EFBatchOperation.For(ctx, ctx.SearchedUserItems).Where(r => subList.Any(a => a == r.ItemID)).Delete(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    castedEndedItems.RemoveRange(0, subList.Count);
    Console.WriteLine("Completed a batch of ended items");
  }
```

As you can see guys I take a batch of 4000 items to delete at once and I pass them as argument to the query...

I'm using this library to perform bulk delete:

```
https://github.com/MikaelEliasson/EntityFramework.Utilities
```

However the performance like this is absolutely terrible... I tested the application couple of times and to delete the 80000 records for example it takes literally 40 minutes!?

I should note that that parameter by which I'm deleting (ItemID) is of varchar(400) type and it's indexed for performance reasons....

Is there any other library that I could possibly use or tweak this query to make it work faster, because currently the performance is absolutely terrible.. :/

Comment: are you deleting everything? or just a subset of the rows? (i.e. would `truncate table` be an option?)

Comment: Use a SQL statement with Entity Framework raw queries.  See [here](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2018/04/01/leveraging-raw-sql.aspx) for examples.  Performance should be almost instantaneous.

Comment: @MarcGravell no as you can see I have a list where only matching items have to be deleted by parameter called "ItemID" - which is of varchar(250) type :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think SQLBulkCompy library implementation would be much better no ? SQLBulkCopy is made for these types of things.. I just wasn't able to find any with good implementation ^^

Comment: Are you doing bulk copy or bulk delete?

Comment: @RobertHarvey bulk delete ^^ you can see from the query up above that I wrote :)

Comment: Then use a raw SQL query.  SQL Server will hardly notice on 50,000 records.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes but notice that I have a list of ID's that need to be passed all at once ...

Comment: @RobertHarvey Also I'm not using .net core , but regular .net framework ^^

Comment: Then use a subquery or Common Table Expression.  Trust me, standard SQL is the way to go here.

Comment: Information on how to do raw queries in EF6 can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql

Comment: In Entity Framework Core you can use `.RemoveRange(...)` You can read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1

Comment: @SebastianSiemens removerange performance is utterly terrible :/

Comment: If you don’t need change tracking (i.e. to perform writes), add `.AsNoTracking()` to your query to ensure it will not be loaded into the context. The context attachment takes some time, and so does a call to `.SaveChanges()` if you have a couple of queries – one that requires changes and one that does not. This is exacerbated if there are a lot of results from those queries.

Comment: If you are simply changing a number of objects, you may not be aware that EF will check whether each of those new objects has changed. To avoid this, turn off `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` before chenging/deleting, then back on again afterwards. It does exactly what its name suggests.

Comment: Is your ItemId a foreign key elsewhere? It may be that you need better indexing in related tables.Your problem may not be any statement or library.

Answer (score 7):

If you are prepared to use a stored procedure then you can do this without any external library:

- Create the sproc using a table valued parameter `@ids`
- Define a SQL type for that table valued parameter (just an `id` column assuming a simple PK)
- In the sproc use

  ```
  delete from table where id in (select id from @ids);
  ```
- In your application create a `DataTable` and populate to match the SQL table
- Pass the data table as an command parameter when calling the sproc.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10409710/67392) illustrates the process.

Any other option will need to do the equivalent of this – or something less efficient.

Comment: There might be a limit on how many ids you can pass this way.

Comment: @RobertHarvey a TVP can have any number of rows; personally I'd probably still loop, though, as a *huge* batch could have trx issues

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, but it is vastly more than the numbers talked about here (likely limited by the SQL Server batch size...). If that is an issue then do 10,000 at a time :-)

Answer (score 4):

any EF solution here is probably going to perform *lots* of discreet operations. Instead, I would suggest manually building your SQL in a loop, something like:

```
using(var cmd = db.CreateCommand())
{
    int index = 0;
    var sql = new StringBuilder("delete from [SomeTable] where [SomeId] in (");
    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        if (index != 0) sql.Append(',');
        var name = "@id_" + index++;
        sql.Append(name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(name, item.SomeId);            
    }
    cmd.CommandText = sql.Append(");").ToString();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

You may need to loop *this* in batches, though, as there is an upper limit on the number of parameters allowed on a command.

Comment: Marc thx for the reply, I'd always prefer clean SQL statement instead of EF for performing batch deletions since it's much better... What do you think how much time would  this take to delete 50000 records n table that totally has 180 million records?

Comment: @User987 Too much depends on the size of the records, whether the PK is clustered, what other indexes exist (their entries will need to be removed as well. And what kind of hardware you have,

Comment: P.S. The way how I match the items is by ItemID which is of type "Varchar"... I guess this causes performance bottleneck ?

Comment: @Marc Gravell so I'm guessing this would  be even better than SQLBulkCopy ?

Comment: @Marc Gravell I've tried to use this piece of code but it says for example: "CreateCommand" doesn't exists in the context...

Comment: I prefer to do it with less statements, but I do also prefer to create a SQL statement with parameters instead of concatenating a string.

Comment: @User987 ultimately you need to get all the ids to the server, which will take some amount of bandwidth; as Richard notes, you could also use a table-valued-parameter to do the same thing - swings/roundabouts

Comment: @User987 in my code, I'm assuming that `db` is an ADO.NET `DbConnection` instance, not an EF context. You'll need a connection, and *that* most definitely has a `CreateCommand` method

Comment: Awesome code, I have been searching SO for nearly a year to find a Bulk delete and finally stumbled on this code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind the extra dependency, you could use the NuGet package Z.EntityFramework.Plus.

The code is roughly as follows:

```
using Z.EntityFramework.Plus;
[...]
         using (yourDbContext context = new yourDbContext())
         {
              yourDbContext.yourDbSet.Where( yourWhereExpression ).Delete();
         }
```

It is simple and efficient. The [documentation](https://entityframework-extensions.net) contains exact numbers about the performance.

Regarding licensing: As far as I know, version 1.8 has an MIT license: https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/blob/master/LICENSE
The newer version are not free to use.

Comment: I'm aware of this one but this is commercial library and it's not a free one... It's highly expensive :)

Comment: As far as I know, there is one with MIT license: https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/blob/master/LICENSE

Comment: wait really ? Since when did they change it to MIT licence :O

Comment: Holy shit it really is MIT licence.. I've read so much about that library that it's awesome... I had no idea they offer it for free now ?o.O

Comment: I think it's an older version, but the NuGet package of version 1.8 links this license. The new version from the project page is 3.1... So 1.8 might not have the best performance and the coolest code style, but it might be worth a try.