# How to use stored procedure result as a sub query in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have a C# code that executes the SQL query. The input of the SQL query comes from a result of a stored procedure. The stored procedure returns a table 6 columns and 25,000 rows. I want to use this stored procedure result as an input to the SQL query. I am storing the stored procedure result in a DataSet. It looks like it's not the correct way to add DataSet results in the query. I need help here experts

Here is what I am doing.

```
public static void ExecuteSQLQueryTest(string qryName, Boolean nestedQry, string spName)
{
    DataTable dtLocalResult = new DataTable();
    DataTable dtAzurelResult = new DataTable();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    List<string> lstring = new List<string>();
    aadSQLConnection.Open();
    //Connection to CPDashboard DB
    var cpdbconnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CATSQL"].ConnectionString);
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = cpdbconnection;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = spName;

        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
    }

    string qryName = "Update A SET A.Environment = B.SC_MD_Environment, A.OSImage = B.SC_APMD_OSImage FROM" + dt + " A"
        + "INNER JOIN[CLOUD].cloudsql.caa.aa_AT_S B ON A.ServerName = B.SC_APMD_MachineName";

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = aadSQLConnection;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = qryName;
        using (SqlDataAdapter daa = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            daa.Fill(dt1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work, you cannot just concatenate a data table *object* to a SQL Query *string*

Comment: If you're getting 25K rows from a stored proc, I'm not sure how you would want to include that in a SQL query.

Comment: Your best option, in my opinion, write a new stored proc, this will internally call the original stored proc to populate a table variable, or temp table, which can then be used to perform the update. You then call the *new* stored proc from your C# app.

Comment: It sounds like table valued parameters are what you are looking for 
(?): 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409576/pass-table-valued-parameter-using-ado-net
But note that returning 25,000 rows to the client, then resending them back to the server may not be a very efficient way of doing things - IF you aren't going to do anything else with that table on the client.

Comment: Why not use a `SELECT` query that selects from the result of the stored procedure? `SELECT * FROM my_stored_procedure`. This way you can skip the step of storing the SP result in a datatable.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing `cell value` of your `DataTable` should be in this format

```
dt[row index][col index]
```

And also, we need to put space in between your `Table` and `From`

```
string qryName = "Update A SET A.Environment = B.SC_MD_Environment, A.OSImage = B.SC_APMD_OSImage "
        + "FROM " + dt[0][0] + " A"
        + "INNER JOIN[CLOUD].cloudsql.caa.aa_AT_S B ON A.ServerName = B.SC_APMD_MachineName";
```

If you are trying to update your `datatable` from your stored procedure output. you need to use `select` query for your cloud table instead, then update your `datatable`.

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    string qryName = "select Environment from [CLOUD].cloudsql.caa.aa_AT_S B where A.ServerName = '"+row["ServerName"].ToString()+"'";

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = aadSQLConnection;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = qryName;
        using (SqlDataAdapter daa = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            .....update your datable here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't C# take entire DataTable as input in this case?. Getting "Can apply indexing with [] to an expression of type DataTable

Comment: @Umapathy, no you cant.

Comment: thank you Guys, i am using select query first and then updating my datatable. This works.