# Assigning TextBox Input to Variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have the following TextBox and Button:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="input" runat="server" Height="10px" Width="60px">123456</asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="ViewButton_Click" Text="Button" />
```

The TextBox has a default value of '123456'. Clicking the botton should then trigger the following:

```
public byte[] GetImageData(int ID)
    {

     ....

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select FileImage from TestServ.dbo.Tickets WHERE (FileType = 'PDF' AND ID = 111111)", connection);

     ....

    }
```

Currently, the ID is manually set to '111111', which will be used to grab a PDF from a server corresponding to the ID entered. What I'm having trouble doing however is modifying the code so that it grabs the ID I enter into the 'input' TextBox (currently 123456) and then sets it as the ID in the above code rather than '111111'.

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377506/pass-array-parameter-in-sqlcommand is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass use parameterized query like

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select FileImage from TestServ.dbo.Tickets WHERE (FileType = 'PDF' AND ID = @ID)", connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", input.Text);
```

Note: Assuming `GetImageData` function is in code behind

Comment: I would at least parse the `TextBox` to make sure it's worth making a db call.

Answer (score 4):

You could simply try to convert the content of the input textbox to an integer using the [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) method and then call the `GetImageData` method passing the converted value.

Of course, in `GetImageData` you use a parameterized query to pass the ID as a parameter to the framework code that queries the database

```
public byte[] GetImageData(int ID)
{

    string cmdText = "select FileImage from TestServ.dbo.Tickets " + 
                     "WHERE (FileType = 'PDF' AND ID = @id)";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmdText, connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);

    ....

}
```

calling code.....

```
int ID;
if(Int32.TryParse(input.Text, out ID))
    byte[] result = GetImageData(ID);

else

  .... show an error ....
```

Comment: Thank you for teaching me the `TryParse()` method!  That's my new thing for the day.

Comment: @CodeswithHammer Thanks to you, your words are more rewarding than the 30 reps. Glad to be of help.