# Pass a list to SqlCommand in asp.net / c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, list

Is there a way to pass a list into a `SqlCommand` so it doesn’t try to convert the string to int? IE:

I can do this:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT  * FROM  modules WHERE (moduleID IN (2,3,4))", connection);
```

But this tries to convert it and breaks

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT  * FROM  modules WHERE (moduleID IN (@modulelist))", connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@modulelist", "2,3,4");
```

Comment: You pass a **single** string which is not working. Use seperate values

Comment: You did try to google the exact words in your question right? And you did come upon this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377506/pass-array-parameter-in-sqlcommand right?

Comment: Not sure I like the duplicate - a stored procedure with a TVP might be a better approach here than looping through a bunch of values one at a time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102358/how-to-pass-an-array-into-a-sql-server-stored-procedure