# SQL Server : parameter not evaluating in AND part of clause

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

The following SQL query with parameters works:

```
select A from B where C = @param1;
```

C#:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", "TEXT");
```

NOTE: `C` is a column of string type

The following SQL Query with parameters does not work:

```
select A from B where C = @param1 and D in (@param2);
```

C#:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", "123,234,456");
```

NOTE: `D` is a column of `int` type

Comment: Did you mean `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", "123,234,456");` ?

Comment: Using parameters in wrong way

Comment: The `IN (...)` expects a **list of values** - while what you're providing is only a **single string**....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer link below, they also pass array to SQL `IN` clause

```
var parameters = new string[items.Length];
var cmd = new SqlCommand();
for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
{
    parameters[i] = string.Format("@Age{0}", i);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameters[i], items[i]);
}

cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT * from TableA WHERE Age IN ({0})", string.Join(", ", parameters));
cmd.Connection = new SqlConnection(connStr);
```

For details please refer: [Pass Array Parameter in SqlCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377506/pass-array-parameter-in-sqlcommand)  answered by @Brian

Answer (score 4):

Because you can't parameterize an `in` like that; you are currently asking for an `in` on a single value that happens to be a string with commas in it - i.e. this will only work if there is a row where `D` is equal to `123,234,456`.

You need to *either* have a parameter **per value** i.e.

```
... and D in (@param2, @param3, @param4)
```

or use a tool that does this for you. For example, with "dapper":

```
string c = "TEXT"; 
int[] vals = { 123, 234, 456 };
var data = conn.Query<AType>("select A from B where C = @c and D in @vals",
      new { c, vals }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

It does work.  It just doesn't do what you expect.  The expression:

```
D in (@param2)
```

Is really doing:

```
D = (@param2)
```

Because the list consists of only one element.  It is an element that contains commas in it, but it is still only one string.

One way around this is to list explicit parameters:

```
D in (@in1, @in2, @in3, @in4)
```

Or to use a less efficient method such as `like`:

```
',' + @param2 + ',' like '%,' + D + ',%'
```

Note:  this assumes that `D` is a string type.  If a number, then you need to cast it to a character type.