# Query with C# with a list as parameter

Tags: c#

I'm want to refactor the following statement to change the `where businessID = something` to  a statement where I provide a list of strings which contain  all possible Ids e.g. `where businessID in List`. As now the query is executed in a for loop for each Id, which I'm guessing is not really performant. I can't seem to find information on how to use a List of strings as a parameter in a prepared statement.

```
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SERVER;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;User Instance=False"))
using (SqlCommand myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand())
{
    myConnection.Open();
    myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT BusinessName FROM Businessess WHERE BusinessID = @Param2";
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param2", myParam2);
    using (SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            string businessName = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("BusinessName"));
            MessageBox.Show(businessName);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Sorry, no business found with id = {0}", myParam2));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [It is recommended to not use AddWithValue().](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass Array Parameter in SqlCommand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377506/pass-array-parameter-in-sqlcommand)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx)  instead of equality, by adding comma separated ids in `@Param2`

```
"SELECT BusinessName FROM Businessess WHERE BusinessID IN(@Param2)";
```

[**IN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx)
Determines whether a specified value matches any value in a subquery or a list.

As @Prescott suggested you the way to make a comma separated string from list you can have your `AddWithValue` like

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param2", String.Join(",", list));
```

As a side not try using stored procedure instead of inline queries, see comparison [Stored procedures vs. inline SQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44544/stored-procedures-vs-inline-sql).

Comment: I will add, if you have list `list`, you can do `String.Join(",", list);` to create a comma delimited string to pass into your parameter

Comment: @Prescott isn't that prone to sql injection?

Comment: Naw, you set the parameter to the comma separated id's (string), this is a parameter - so it's escaped properly.

Answer (score 0):

first create convert your list to comma separated string

```
string commaSeparatedList = yourlist.Aggregate((a, x) => a + ", " + x);
```

change the (=) to (In) and put the @Param between parenthesis

```
myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT BusinessName FROM Businessess WHERE BusinessID IN ( @Param2 )";
```

add the string (commaSeparatedList ) as parameter to your command

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param2", commaSeparatedList );
```

Comment: Instead of `Aggregate` you can use `string.Join(", ", yourlist)`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.