# SQL Get a result by a list of Parameters

Tags: c#, sql, parameters

I have this code

```
List<int> userIDList = new List<int>() { 1,2,3,4,5 };
string Command = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM User WHERE UserID in @UserID;";
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Command, myConnection))
    {
        myDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserID", userIDList));
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        myDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work because i can't attach a List into a Parameter

`new SqlParameter("@UserID", userIDList)`

What is the way to go here?

Comment: Use table-valued parameters. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249/t-sql-stored-procedure-that-accepts-multiple-id-values

Comment: @TimSchmelter isn't JaydipJ answer a bit simpler?

Comment: Do you want to get all users?

Comment: JaydipJ's answer is true then.

Comment: ok I was just irritated from Tim's comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to convert List to comma separated string

```
myDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserID",
                                               String.join(",",userIDList)));;
```

then use this string in query like this

```
string Command = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM User WHERE UserID in (@UserID);";
```

Comment: You need one parameter for each value that you pass to `IN`. Like in these answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2377651/284240 But a better(more efficient) way is to use table-valued parameters.

Comment: still both work in similar manner and they both will yield same output

Comment: I have my doubts. Because `UserID` seems to be an `int` column but you are passing a `string`/`varchar`, so i expect the database to refuse it as valid argument. At least if you pass more than one.

Comment: May be what you are trying to say is true, but once i have implemented same in my project and  this works perfectly, and thanks for info.