# C# get variable from textbox and use in ExecuteNonQuery as variable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, executenonquery

I have windows form app.
And all i  need is to load variable from textbox into script while using ExecuteNonQuery .

My code :

```
var connString = @"Data Source=serwer01;Initial Catalog=PolsatCyfrowy;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
FileInfo file = new FileInfo("C:\\Users\\Kolejki.sql");
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
conn.Open();
string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
```

and my script named : Kolejki.sql looks:

```
declare variable1 VARCHAR (50)
set variable1 = '1234'
select * from table1 where id in(@variable1)
```

How can i just set variable1 = (text from textbox1? textbox1.Text)
I just need only to use ExecuteNonQuery because its so long script and can't use SQLCommand - It's just example.

Comment: A Parameterized Query is the way to safely pass data from C# to an SQL statement, however it will not work with `IN()`, see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377506/pass-array-parameter-in-sqlcommand

Comment: Yes i know that , it's only example to explain problem .

Comment: Why don't you use storeprocedures?

Comment: Because don't have permission to create storedprocedure on this server .

Comment: You should get permission to create a stored procedure. Doing this by reading sql from a text file and then executing is a recipe for disaster. It is vulnerable to sql injection and my friend bobby tables loves this type of stuff. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Sounds like a good place to use LINQ - assuming your end game to execute against a collection of ids.

Comment: I dont care about SQL injection. It's gonna me my own program only for me to using can someone just give exmaple how to do that? :(  Just put @variable into script executed by ExecuteNonQuery