# SQL Injection prevention for concatenated string inside IN clause

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, sql-injection

I have a variable which is an array of string. I want to pass all the values of the variable, concatenating all elements of it into a single string.

But I'm not sure whether this poses risks of SQL injection.
My code:

```
private string concatenateStrings(string[] sa)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (string s in sa)
    {
        if (sb.Length > 0)
        {
            sb.Append(",");
        }
        sb.Append("'");
        sb.Append(s);
        sb.Append("'");
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}

public void UpdateClaimSts(string[] ids)
{
    string query = @"UPDATE MYTABLE
                    SET STATUS = 'X'
                    WHERE TABLEID in (" + concatenateStrings(ids) + ")";

    OracleCommand dbCommand = (OracleCommand)this.Database.GetSqlStringCommand(query) as OracleCommand;
    this.Database.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand, this.Transaction);
}
```

I tried changing the query to use parameterized queries:

```
string query = @"UPDATE MYTABLE
                SET STATUS = 'X'
                WHERE TABLEID in (:ids)";

OracleCommand dbCommand = (OracleCommand)this.Database.GetSqlStringCommand(query) as OracleCommand;

dbCommand.Parameters.Add(":ids", OracleType.VarChar).Value = concatenateStrings(ids);
this.Database.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand, this.Transaction);
```

But it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mydata", ids)

Comment: In your first example, if my first `id` is `1');DROP TABLE MYTABLE;--` (for example) then you'll have some trouble

Comment: @TrishSiquian It does not work. Basically what you do is the same of what I try to do in my second example.

Comment: @Rafalon That's why I ask for suggestion on how to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: @rcs Yes, I was just answering to this: "*But I'm not sure whether this poses risks of SQL injection*"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass Array Parameter in SqlCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377506/pass-array-parameter-in-sqlcommand)

Comment: Unrelated, but your `concatenateStrings` could just as well `return "'"+String.Join("','",sa)+"'";` :)

Comment: Are your ids really strings? if they are int then you can pass int[] ids and that would do it. Same with GUIDs. But if it's really strings, then dunno.

Comment: You can check if all the ids (items of `string[] sa`) are in fact integers: `Regex.IsMatch(item @"^\-?[0-9]+$")`

Comment: @Rafalon Unlike some databases, Oracle does not allow two commands in a single statement so that type of SQL injection attack will throw an error. There are other methods of attack that would work like `1) OR 1=1` to bypass the filter and update every row or `1) AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM password_table WHERE user = 'Admin' AND hash = '0123456' )` to look for the existence of other tables and sensitive data.

Comment: Just a note, this approach will fail if you have more than 4000 elements. I don't know whether this is relevant in your case.

Comment: It's ok, I don't have that many elements

Comment: @MT0 That's good to know, thanks. I actually didn't see the `oracle` tag, but didn't know that either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick and *partial* (we assume `TABLEID` field be of type `NUMBER`) solution you can verify that *each item* in `sa` is a *valid integer*:

```
private string concatenateStrings(string[] sa) {
   return string.Join(", ", sa
     .Where(item => Regex.IsMatch(item, @"^\-?[0-9]+$"))); 
} 

public void UpdateClaimSts(string[] ids) {
  string query = string.Format(
    @"UPDATE MYTABLE
         SET STATUS = 'X'
       WHERE TABLEID IN ({0})", concatenateStrings(ids));
      ...
```

In general case, you can try using *bind variables* (please, notice *plural*: we have to create *many* of them):

```
public void UpdateClaimSts(string[] ids) {  
  // :id_0, :id_1, ..., :id_N   
  string bindVariables = string.Join(", ", ids
    .Select((id, index) => ":id_" + index.ToString()));

  string query = string.Format(
    @"UPDATE MYTABLE
         SET STATUS = 'X'
       WHERE TABLEID IN ({0})", bindVariables);

  // Do not forget to wrap IDisposable into "using"
  using (OracleCommand dbCommand = ...) {
    ...
    // Each item of the ids should be assigned to its bind variable
    for (int i = 0; i < ids.Length; ++i)
      dbCommand.Parameters.Add(":id_" + i.ToString(), OracleType.VarChar).Value = ids[i];

   ...
```

Comment: "you can verify that each item in sa is a valid integer" -- If everything is supposed to be an integer, the OP can just update the parameter to `int[]` instead of `string[]` and avoid the regex. Your second suggestion looks good to me though.

Comment: @hvd: not necessary - RDMS `Number` and .Net `int` (`long`) can well be quite different types (e.g. `Number(20)` exceeds `long`), that's why `int[]` instead of `string[]` is a dangerous desicion. However we often use `Number(N)` as a key and in this case my first partial solution will work

Comment: Read `decimal[]` instead of `int[]`, then. My point was that your assumption that everything must be an integer is just that, an assumption. There is nothing preventing `TABLEID` from being a text column, and the fact that the OP *didn't* use `int[]` or `long[]` or `decimal[]` is at least a weak indication that it's not an integer column.

Comment: Is it possible if you do not use interpolated string? So that it can support legacy .net framework too ?

Comment: @rcs: Sure, interpolated strings can be changed into their `string.Format` equivalents

Answer (score 3):

Create a PL/SQL procedure (inside a PL/SQL Package) like this:

```
TYPE TArrayOfVarchar2 IS TABLE OF MYTABLE.TABLEID%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

PROCEDURE UPDATE_MYTABLE(TABLEIDs IN TArrayOfVarchar2) IS
BEGIN

    FORALL i IN INDICES OF TABLEIDs
    UPDATE MYTABLE SET STATUS = 'X' WHERE TABLEID = TABLEIDs(i);

END;
```

and make a call like this:

```
using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("BEGIN UPDATE_MYTABLE(:tableId); END;"), con))
{
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  // or
  // OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("UPDATE_MYTABLE"), con);
  // cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  var par = cmd.Parameters.Add("tableId", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);
  par.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
  par.Value = sa;
  par.Size = sa.Length;

  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I may not be able to create the procedure in the database for some reason, and hence prefers a solution that can be done in C#.

Answer (score 0):

C# has a `OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray` type for passing arrays to a PL/SQL Associative Array data type but this cannot be used in SQL queries as it is only a PL/SQL data structure.

It, unfortunately, does not support passing an array to an SQL Collection data type (which could be used in an SQL query).

One work around for this is to ask your DBA to create a simple function to convert a PL/SQL Associative Array to an SQL collection and then use this as an intermediate step in the query:

```
CREATE TYPE varchar2s_array_type IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100)
/

CREATE PACKAGE utils IS
  TYPE varchar2s_assoc_array_type IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100) INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

  FUNCTION assoc_array_to_collection(
    p_assoc_array IN varchar2s_assoc_array_type
  ) RETURN varchar2s_array_type DETERMINISTIC;
END;
/

CREATE PACKAGE BODY utils IS
  FUNCTION assoc_array_to_collection(
    p_assoc_array IN varchar2s_assoc_array_type
  ) RETURN varchar2s_array_type DETERMINISTIC
  IS
    p_array varchar2s_array_type := varchar2s_array_type();
    i PLS_INTEGER;
  BEGIN
    IF p_assoc_array IS NOT NULL THEN
      i := p_assoc_array.FIRST;
      LOOP
        EXIT WHEN i IS NULL;
        p_array.EXTEND();
        p_array(p_array.COUNT) := p_assoc_array(i);
        i := p_assoc_array.NEXT(i);
      END LOOP;
    END IF;
    RETURN p_array;
  END;
END;
/
```

Then you can change your code to use `MEMBER OF` rather than `IN` within the SQL statement:

```
UPDATE MYTABLE
SET    STATUS = 'X'
WHERE  TABLEID MEMBER OF utils.assoc_array_to_collection(:ids)
```

And bind the parameter using something like (*I'm not a C# user so this is just to give you a general idea of the method, even if the syntax is not entirely correct*):

```
var par = cmd.Parameters.Add(":ids", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);
par.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
par.Value = ids;
par.Size = ids.Length;
cmd.ExecuteQuery();
```

Then you can reuse the generic function across many queries.