# How to pass comma separated column values from sql sever in a variable in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, sql-server

In my table I have inserted values from multiple dropdowns now I want to pass those values in where clause of my c# code how to do it please help

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select distinct comp_type from master_office_complaint 
where comp_id='" + reader["marked_officer"]+ "'", conn);
```

Here `marked_officer` column contains multiple values.

Comment: You need a `WHERE comp_id IN (...)` clause. Now, the goal is to make this query protected against SQL injections.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass Array Parameter in SqlCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377506/pass-array-parameter-in-sqlcommand)

Comment: i have tried using in clause but i m getting zero response

Comment: Use parameters, to be safe from sql injection your query should be : select distinct comp_type from master_office_complaint where comp_id in (select value from string_split(@marked_officer, ','))

Comment: @MarcGuillot i am getting this error -System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@marked_officer".'

Comment: what does reader["marked_officer"] value look like?

Comment: @SZT its a sql server table's column with multiple comma separated values like (,12,4,5) etc basically i have inserted values form dropdown <select class="select2 select2-multiples form-control" multiple="true" runat="server"> in marked_officer column

Comment: so you mean the column itself contains a value like (12, 4,5)? not like row[1].column["mo"] = 12, row[2].column["mo"] = 4 ? I would suggest please put the sql command in a string and look at the resultant string. If it's still confusing please put the resultant string here so we can take a look

Comment: marked_officer
                12,11,10
                ,12,10
                 1 ,2
this is how my table coumn looks like

Comment: And what's the value of "select distinct comp_type from master_office_complaint 
where comp_id='" + reader["marked_officer"]+ "'"?? do something like this:

string pQuery = "select distinct comp_type from master_office_complaint 
where comp_id='" + reader["marked_officer"]+ "'"

Console.WriteLine(pQuery)

it will allow you to look at the sql query you are trying to generate.

Comment: @SZT in return i m getting this output select distinct comp_type from master_office_complaint where comp_id= '12 .....it means among 4 column data i m getting just first one :(

Comment: That means reader["marked_officer"] doesn't have all the values you need, you need to iterate through your record and generate a string that holds all the values you are looking for, and also your query should look like this .... where comp_id in ('your_New_string_Variable')

Comment: no column does have all the values but query not fetching all so can u explain more about iteration like if i apply for loop then how?

Comment: SqlCommand command3 = new SqlCommand("select distinct comp_type from master_office_complaint where comp_id =" + reader["marked_officer"].ToString() + "", conn2);
                        using (SqlDataReader reader3 = command3.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader3.Read())
                            {
                                source_name = reader3["comp_type"].ToString();

                            }

                            reader3.Close();
                        }this is how part of code looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the below answer on SQL Server.

SELECT DISTINCT comp_type 
FROM master_office_complaint
WHERE comp_id IN ('ID1','ID2','ID3')