# Passing list of IDs to WHERE IN from C# code

Tags: c#, sql, sqlcommand

Challenging issue you have encountered already ?

This is my challenge.

I have the query as follows - MSSQL Server 2017 calling from my C# application.

**SQL**

```
update slides set isBorrowed=0, updated_by='Daniel'
where id in (1,2,3);
```

**C# code to achieve above**

'Update Slides SET isBorrowed=1,updated_by=@update_by
 WHERE id IN (@ids)'

```
   string updateDonorQuery = "UPDATE slides " +
                            "SET isBorrowed=1,updated_by=@updated_by WHERE id IN (@ids)";
                        command.CommandText = updateDonorQuery;
                        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ids",list_ids.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).toList());
                   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@updated_by", "Full name
```

Now The error is saying : "Exception on my command not expecting to receive list"

Then , i have changed to a string like this:

```
string list_ids = "1,2,3";

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ids",list_ids);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@updated_by", "Full name")
```

Agin code throw exception that complainant i have passed in nvarchar values instead of int.
I guess interested the code as '1,2,3' when getting ids.

**Guys i need a breakthrough , i hate loops.**

Comment: Pass another parameter '@updated_by'.

Comment: it is passed let me edit the code

Comment: You could create a table-type variable and pass the values as a table parameter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass Array Parameter in SqlCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377506/pass-array-parameter-in-sqlcommand)

Comment: Your question conflicts with the sql-server-2008 tag. If you are using SQL 2017, simply change the `IN` clause in the query to `IN(SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@ids,','))`. Also, [avoid `AddWithValue`](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: @DanGuzman Thanks worked like a charm and took your advise for addwithValue. Thanks