# Wrong results from a query through .NET connector but correct results directly in Teradata Studio

Tags: teradata

When I execute the below code, the result is `0`:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select count(1) from dbc.tablesv where databasename = ? and TableKind in (?, ?) and tablename = ?";
cmd.Parameters.Add("db", TdType.VarChar).Value = dbName;
cmd.Parameters.Add("prc", TdType.VarChar).Value = objName;
cmd.Parameters.Add("p", TdType.Char).Value = 'P';
cmd.Parameters.Add("e", TdType.Char).Value = 'E';
if ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 0)
{}
```

But if I run the same query with the same values as supplied above, in Teradata Studio, then it returns `1`. This is on Teradata 17, client provider 17.0.2, and .NET full framework 4.7.2.

How am I supposed to pass parameters to a query through .NET connector, to receive correct results? It probably has something to do with `IN` clause, because right before this failing query the same code that uses

```
select count(1) from dbc.TablesV where databasename = ? and tablename = ? and tablekind = ?
```

succeeds, with the correct result of `1` for a table that is related to the procedure I am looking for.

I confirmed that if both parameters of the `IN` clause are hardcoded literals, then the query returns the correct results. If at least one of them is a parameter, then the query does not work.

Comment: this looks more like you have the wrong parameters and should ask in SO for help.

Comment: It may not be possible to build a parameterized array like that. Could you take one of [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377506/pass-array-parameter-in-sqlcommand/2377651#2377651) and adapt it to your query?